# Where can I find Carandol (the red mushroom)?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I need a few of these Carandol for the eighth survival challenge, but the only one I found is in the caves of the upper right corner of the second world. Are there any easier locations for this? Videos and guides online weren't much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom-right part of the second world is a cave that should have one red mushroom (Carandol). Just outside and to the left is a bridge. Underneath it, on its far end, should be two more herbs.